# python - Yield improperly usage

Tags: python, parsing, yield, gensim

Im pretty sure im using yield improperly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint  # pretty-printer
from six import iteritems
import openpyxl
import string
from operator import itemgetter

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

#Creating a stoplist from file
with open('stop-word-list.txt') as f:
    stoplist = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]

corpusFileName = 'content_sample_en.xlsx'
corpusSheetName = 'content_sample_en'

class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(corpusFileName)
        sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(corpusSheetName)
        for i in range(1, (sheet.max_row+1)/2):
            title = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 4).value.encode('utf-8'))
            summary = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 5).value.encode('utf-8'))
            content = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 10).value.encode('utf-8'))
            yield reBuildDoc("{} {} {}".format(title, summary, content))


def removeUnwantedPunctuations(doc):
    "change all (/, \, <, >) into ' ' "
    newDoc = ""
    for l in doc:
        if  l == "<" or l == ">" or l == "/" or l == "\\":
            newDoc += " "
        else:
            newDoc += l
    return newDoc

def reBuildDoc(doc):
    """
    :param doc:
    :return: document after being dissected to our needs.
    """
    doc = removeUnwantedPunctuations(doc).lower().translate(None, string.punctuation)
    newDoc = [word for word in doc.split() if word not in stoplist]
    return newDoc

corpus = MyCorpus()

tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus, normalize=True)
```

In the following example you can see me trying to create a corpus from an xlsx file. Im reading from the xlsx file 3 lines which are title summary and content and appending them into a big string. my `reBuildDoc()` and `removeUnwantedPunctuations()` functions then adjust the text to my needs and in the end returns a big list of words. (for ex: `[hello, piano, computer, etc... ]`) in the end I yield the result but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Eran/PycharmProjects/tfidf/docproc.py", line 101, in <module>
    tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus, normalize=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.13.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\gensim\models\tfidfmodel.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.initialize(corpus)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.13.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\gensim\models\tfidfmodel.py", line 119, in initialize
    for termid, _ in bow:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I know the error is from the yield line because I had a different yield line that worked. It looked like this:

```
 yield [word for word in dictionary.doc2bow("{} {} {}".format(title, summary, content).lower().translate(None, string.punctuation).split()) if word not in stoplist]
```

It was abit messy and hard to put functionallity to it so I've changed it as you can see in the first example.

Comment: Side-note: `removeUnwantedPunctuations` is implemented incredibly inefficiently, particularly since you're performing a `translate` call on the result anyway. Just run the following at the top level of your code `unwanted_to_space, deletepunc = string.maketrans(r'\/<>', '    '), string.punctuation.translate(None, r'\/<>')`, then change `doc = removeUnwantedPunctuations(doc).lower().translate(None, string.punctuation)` to `doc = doc.translate(unwanted_to_space, deletepunc).lower()`. In simple tests, that reduces run time by a factor of ~10-15x (higher end for longer/less punctuated strings).

Comment: And you could save even more by making `unwanted_to_space` with `string.maketrans(r'\/<>' + string.ascii_uppercase, '    ' + string.ascii_lowercase)` (if it's not visible, there should be four spaces in the string that leads the second argument), which allows you to omit the call to `lower` (if the input was non-ASCII, you'd want true `lower`, but for ASCII `str`, incorporating the work in the `translate` call is equivalent and free), getting a >20x savings on runtime. Obviously, if your inputs are small, the savings doesn't matter, but for big data, parsing input could be a big cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not the `yield` per se, is what is yielded, the error said is from `for termid, _ in bow` this line said that you expect that `bow` contain a list of tuples or any other object containing exactly 2 element like `(1,2),[1,2],"12",...` but as it end giving to it the result of `MyCorpus` which is a string with obviously more than 2 element, hence the error, to fix this do either `for termid in bow` or in `MyCorpus` do `yield reBuildDoc("{} {} {}".format(title, summary, content)), None` so you yield a tuple of 2 object

to illustrate this check this example

```
>>> def fun(obj):
        for _ in range(2):
            yield obj


>>> for a,b in fun("xyz"):
        print(a,b)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    for a,b in fun("xyz"):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>>> for a,b in fun("xy"):
        print(a,b)


x y
x y
>>> for a,b in fun(("xy",None)):
        print(a,b)


xy None
xy None
>>>
```

Comment: You are right, The problem was with the other function. I needed to do dictionary.doc2bow on the document before yielding it. And as you've written it does accept tuples. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is describing immediate cause of the eventual symptom, but the real solution is not just "add a fake second element", and the true cause is much higher level; `TfidfModel` requires input in a specific form, and adding faked second elements wouldn't make the code work either.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is that `TfidfModel` expects a `corpus` that is a `list` of `doc2bow` outputs (themselves `list`s of two-`tuple`s). Your original working code used `doc2bow` correctly to convert from your plain strings to the corpus format, your new code is passing in raw strings, not the "vectors" `TfidfModel` expects.

Go back to using `doc2bow`, and [read the tutorial on converting string to vectors](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#from-strings-to-vectors), which makes it clear that raw strings are nonsensical as input.